# Method returning a List<T> with parameters List<S1>, List<S2>, where S1 and S2 extends T

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, java-stream

I have this method:

```
public static <T> List<T> flat(List<T>... lists){
    return Stream.of(lists)
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(toList());
}
```

The idea is to flat a list of lists and return a list with the same type.

Suppose that `A` and `B` extends `C`. This does not work:

```
List<A> listOfA;
List<B> listOfB;
List<C> listOfC = flat(listOfA, listOfB);
```

Because `List<A>` is not a `List<C>`!

Anyone know how to write a flat method signature with generics that admits what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the relation between `A`, `B` and `C`?

Comment: @user7 he mentioned that A and b extending c

Comment: btw instead of `Stream.of(lists)` you should use `Arrays.stream(lists)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `A` extends `C`, `B` extends `C`, then `List<A>` and `List<B>` are assignable to `List<? extends C>`.

So you can declare it this way:

```
public static <T> List<T> flat(List<? extends T>... lists)
```

Test:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> listOfString = List.of("sss"); // String extends from Object
    List<Integer> listOfInt = List.of(1); // Integer extends from Object
    List<Object> list = flat(listOfString, listOfInt);
    System.out.println(list); // [sss, 1]
}
```

Comment: For reference, this is called a [Bounded Wildcard Type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

Comment: @TimKlein ... and an upper bounded wildcard makes the type covariant.